# React Metarial ui redirect to another tab after submission?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui, formik, formik-material-ui

I have a /home route that has two tabs, after submitting a form (I use Formik) I want to redirect the user to the first tab in the same route. So basically

```
 onSubmit: (values) => {
  dispatch(actions.userAdded(values));
  history.push(`/home`); // ??
},
```

doesn't work out. What is the best solution?

I am using MUI basic tab model.

```
 <AppBar position="static" color="default"> 
    <Tabs
      value={value}
      onChange={handleChange}
      indicatorColor="primary"
      textColor="primary"
      variant="fullWidth"
      aria-label="Rules"
    >
      <Tab label="Your Rules" {...a11yProps(0)} />
      <Tab label="Add New Rule" {...a11yProps(1)} />
    </Tabs>
  </AppBar>
  <SwipeableViews
    axis={theme.direction === 'rtl' ? 'x-reverse' : 'x'}
    index={value}
    onChangeIndex={handleChangeIndex}
  >
    <TabPanel value={value} index={0} dir={theme.direction}>
      <DisplayUsers /> // I WANT TO GO HERE AFTER SUBMITION
    </TabPanel>
    <TabPanel value={value} index={1} dir={theme.direction}>
    <AddUsers />  // HERE I HAVE FORM 
    </TabPanel>
  </SwipeableViews>
```

Comment: pass your handleChangeIndex to your AppUsers component and change the index when submit form. Tabs doesn't link to your history.

Comment: well I have many different form components inside AddUsers component. I don't want to repeat the code and pass the handleChangeIndex too deep.. Do you think it is the only way to do it?

Comment: if u don't want to pass props too deep, you can create a Provider using context API.  Right now, I can not think of other solution

Comment: @VoQuocThang just discovered redux is invented to solve this problem lol